# How to use external HD video camera as input for a Visual Studio, OpenCV project?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, external, gopro

I am doing a project regarding image processing and multiple person counting and was wondering, how exactly can I plug my ION AIR PRO PLUS video recording device (similar to a goPro), and use it as my 'webcam'? Basically, I want to plug it in and then access it via a live feed using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and OpenCV, and then do real time tracking of people walking.

What I am struggling with is accessing the external camera from my program. Anyone know how to do this?

The video camera has no wifi, only an hdmi output, RGB cable output and a USB.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the VideoCapture class and an openCV tutorial or two?

Comment: Yes I have, index 0 just opens the laptop's webcam, I can open a video by just putting in the name but when I connect the external camera, it isnt recognized as a webcam

Comment: Instead of 0, try each of the numbers 1 through 9.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the USB cable and instantiate `cv::VideoCaputre(0)`. In Linux local cameras have number indices I think in Windows should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Peter, In the past I have worked on camera products on Windows XP & 7. On windows usb cameras can be accessed using directshow.

You can implement a directshow filter for people tracking algorithm and fit it in the direct show pipeline soon after your camera plugin.

Here is a link to an application stack that may suit your use case(to give you an idea):
http://www.e-consystems.com/blog/camera/?p=1302

The recent windows operating systems that run WinRT, use a latest framework called MediaFoundation. As its very new there are some limitations we found when we tried to build similar applications.

To quickly see a preview out of your camera, pls google for "graphedit" and install it on a Windows 7 pc. Its a fairly simple tool. You can drag and drop your camera, if directshow is supported, then render its output pin and play for preview.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is a standard webcam, it appears to work only as a mass storage device. One thing you can try is removing the micro sd card and connect it to the computer. This works on some cameras.

Assuming this does not work, one option would be to purchase an HDMI capture card. The YK762H PCI-E card costs around $40, and will allow you to use the camera with OpenCV, the videoInput library, or DirectShow.

The other option is to use the WiFi live preview. You would have to figure out the commands sent to the camera. This has already been done with the SJCam wifi cameras, the GoPro models, and Sony cameras such as the QX-10 and HDR-AS100V.